# Show that $\left( \bigoplus _i V_i \right)^* = \prod_i V_i ^*$ canonically

Tags: vector-spaces, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

I am trying to prove that given a sequence of finite dimensional vector spaces $V_i$ (though I think we can be more general, but whatever), I have a canonical isomorphism that gives me:

$$\left( \bigoplus _i V_i \right)^* = \prod_i V_i ^*$$

where $\bigoplus _i V_i$ is the set of sequences whose $i$-th term belongs to $V_i$ that are definitely zero, and $\prod_i V_i$ the set of all sequences whose $j$-th term belongs to $V_j$.

It is trivial with a finite number of terms, but I don't get how to extend it to infinite products, and why you need sequences that are definitely zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in \left ( \oplus_{i \in I} V_i \right )^*$, then for each $i$, $f \upharpoonright V_i \in V_i^*$. Then the product $(f \upharpoonright V_i)_{i \in I}$ lives in $\Pi_{i \in I} V_i^*$.

Notice there is nothing saying that all but finitely many of the $f \upharpoonright V_i$ should be $0$, so $(f \upharpoonright V_i)_{i \in I}$ does not live in $\oplus_{i \in I} V_i^*$, in general!

As for the other direction, given $(f_i)_{i \in I} \in \Pi_{i \in I}V_i^*$, define (for some $J \subseteq I$ finite) $f(\sum a_j v_j) = \sum_{j \in J} a_j f_j(v_j)$ .

Since $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ tells us what to do to each $V_i$, we know (by linearity) what we have to do to a sum of elements of the $V_i$.

I leave it to you to check that these maps are mutually inverse.

---

**Edit:**

More formally, we see $\left ( \oplus_{i \in I} V_i \right )^*\cong \Pi_{i \in I} V_i^*$ since we have maps $\varphi : \left ( \oplus_{i \in I} V_i \right )^* \to \Pi_{i \in I} V_i^*$ and $\psi : \Pi_{i \in I} V_i^* \to \left ( \oplus_{i \in I} V_i \right )^*$ given by

$\varphi(f) = (f \upharpoonright V_i)_{i \in I}$

$\psi((f_i)_{i \in I}) = F$

To define $F : \oplus_{i \in I} V_i \to K$, it suffices to define it on each summand, and then extend linearly. We put $F(v_j) = f_j(v_j)$ for $v_j \in V_j$.

Again, I leave it to you to verify these maps are mutually inverse (and indeed that they are linear maps).

---

But why does this only work with $\oplus V_i$?

For $f \in (\Pi_{i \in I} V_i)^*$, we can *also* consider $f \upharpoonright V_i$, and we can *also* form the product $(f \upharpoonright V_i)_{i \in I} \in \Pi_{i \in I} V_i^*$.

Unfortunately, this new operation is not injective. For simplicity, say each $V_i$ is finite dimensional, so that $|V_i| = |V_i^*|$. Then when $K$ is the underlying field of the vector space:

$|(\Pi_{i \in I} V_i)^*| = |K|^{|\Pi_{i \in I} V_i|} > |\Pi_{i \in I} V_i| = |\Pi_{i \in I} V_i^*|$

Restricting ourselves to only *finite* sums solves this cardinality issue, and allows the function defined above to be injective (indeed bijective).

---

Hope this helps! ^_^

Comment: What do you mean with that vertical arrow? In the first line, for instance

Comment: If $f : A \to B$ is a function, and $U \subseteq A$, the function $(f \upharpoonright U) : U \to B$ is the function sending $u \in U \subseteq A$ to $f(u)$. It is called the _restriction_ of $f$ to $U$.

Comment: Oh, ok, I use another notation. Also, I don't understand if you are trying to prove a double inclusion or if you define a map that is an isomorphism. I thought I had to do te latter, but from youur answer I get that you are saying those spaces are exactly the same, and not "just" canonically isomorphic?

Comment: The spaces are only isomorphic, and what I've done is define mutually inverse maps between the two spaces. I'll update my answer to better reflect this